# How to get xPath of a web element using Selenium Webdriver on Node JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

For example I get an element by using findElement function:

```
let myElement = await driver.findElement(By.id(2));
```

Is it possible to get myElement's xPath using Selenium-webdriver within Node.js?

Comment: how did you get the element should be first question here ?

Comment: according to this website, you cna try this `driver.findElement(web.By.xpath())`. Website -> https://www.tabnine.com/code/javascript/functions/selenium-webdriver/By/xpath

Comment: No, I don't need to find element by xpath. I want to get xpath of current element (myElement in sample)

Comment: No you wouldn't be able to get that. since `myElement` is a web element, associated with id that you have passed.

Comment: Is there any way to get web element's xpath?